# When does local copy of OneNote notebook update?

Tags: sync, microsoft-onenote

I created a OneNote notebook on my C:\ drive using the Windows's version of One Note, and have now shared it on One Drive (cloud).

I then updated the notebook on my android tablet using One Drive, and my Windows version of OneNote shows those changes.  However, I see that my windows OneNote is using the One Drive version of the notebook now.

When/how do I update the copy of the document on my C:\ drive?